# set APPDATA=whatever does not work?

Tags: batch-file, set, dos

Got a exe that saves it's data in AppData.

I want it to save in my own folder eg, /data

I have this:

```
set APPDATA=%cd%\data
```

Not working for some reason :(

Anyone know why?

Thank you.

Comment: _Not working_ is a bit unspecific ... What do you expect? Should it burn a CD or that the appdata is creating a file in a data-directory

Answer (score 1):

The application will be getting hold of the APPDATA path via one of the system APIs, e.g. SHGetFolderPath, rather than reading the environment variable. There's nothing simple that you can do to change its behaviour.